# Strictly convex equivalent norm

Tags: banach-spaces

Does every Banach space admit an equivalent strictly convex norm (i.e. such a norm, that a unit sphere does not contain segments)?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/151956/15129

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Every separable Banach space has an equivalent norm which is both strictly convex and smooth. For certain nonseparable spaces, in particular, $\ell_{\infty}(\Gamma)$ with $\Gamma$ uncountable, there may be no equivalent strictly convex or smooth norm.

[Link.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1A7ppEZPXEIC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=equivalent+strictly+convex+norm&source=bl&ots=zx13lvLJXV&sig=bBaKVMIB4be6BpBQlUcrpQaTEUQ&hl=en&ei=aaMvTM2jH9S5jAeY843DBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=equivalent%20strictly%20convex%20norm&f=false)